# receiving exception when hitting facebook graph URL for oauth request

Tags: facebook, scribe

I am trying to figure out the best possible way for me to debug/verify facebook graph URL's (I am trying to specify permissions in the URL for oauth) e.g.:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,picture,email,likes,interests,gender,id,locale,friends,first_name,last_name,link,user_about_me,friends_about_me&access_token=%s
```

However, I keep receiving an error message mentioning socialauth did not work correctly (I am using scribe/Java in debug mode).  I could not locate other error messages.  I am able to run oauth correctly with scribe using a smaller URL & I am not sure whether the issue is with the permissions I am asking for or the string I am creating. Any insights on how to troubleshoot  or fix the issue will be appreciated.  For any downvoters, seek a life!

Edit:
I am using scribe-java for oauth as mentioned in the post.  I tried the URL above (as I mentioned in the post) but it gave me an exception in scribe (I used debug mode for scribe but I did not see any error messages besides "social auth did not work correctly").  When I try the same URL but without "**user_about_me,friends_about_me**" in the URL, I get a response from Facebook with a successful oauth.  Are the values "user_about_me,friends_about_me" invalid for the oauth URL or perhaps I need to dig deeper into how scribe is communicating this to FB?  I would not be surprised if its something I am doing which is incorrect - I just need to understand how best to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Is the access token used in that request valid? What error message are you receiving? what does your login code look like?

Comment: request token is valid, I am able to login when using a shorter URL as mentioned in my post.  thanks

Comment: You may want to use the Facebook graph explorer for verifying the url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Your question is REALLY unclear as to what you're doing with the API and at what point it fails, and what the error is

Comment: Igy - I updated the post.  If something is unclear, please ask.  Posting something in the comments section in all caps is quite immature/uncivilized - kindly avoid it.

Comment: I could use bold text next time - it's not clear what you're actually doing with the API and where you're receiving the error message - you said it's in the Authorisation step at the start, but gave an example of a call to fetch user data -either way it sounds like your third-part library 'social auth' is swallowing the error from the API - in this case there's no way to know what the problem is

Comment: thanks for looking into it Igy - appreciated.  I have taken out the "user_about_me,friends_about_me" string from the fields section of the URL that was being used for oauth (as before) and I am able to get the basic information for a successfully authenticated user as the response.  I am guessing either the string being passed (or the one the library is converting this into) is inaccurate - I will try adding debug statements to the library or perhaps use wireshark/any other tool etc to capture the generated URL for confirmation.